How to distinguish social psychology from opinion-based questions?
I often come across questions asking about the motivations of some social group, human behaviour or a social phenomena. For example:

“Doomsday preppers” - do they want the World to end?
What causes someone to scapegoat?

Often they get closed because they are "opinion based" or "too broad". Sometimes (perhaps misguidedly) I participate in the closing of these questions, but I feel like I'm mis-using the closing tool, since my reason for closing is often just "I don't like this question".
I need help. Despite taking a first year psychology course in university, I'm still confused about the appropriate use of it here. How does one distinguish a valid social psychology question from one that is purely opinion-based or too broad?

My strategy is to try and imagine the empirical research that would need to exist in order to answer the question. 
If I can't imagine empirical results that would give a reasonably definitive answer on the question, then I'll vote to close as primarily opinion based. 
If I can imagine hypothetical experiments that would be informative, but there are so many of them that a reasonable response to the question would almost certainly be really incomplete, then I'll vote to close as too broad.

Very similar to my own thoughts.

It seems that what question is viable on most SE sites is defined in reference to the available literature. "Too little," and a question becomes opinion-based because there aren't enough "facts or references" to support an answer. "Too much," and the question becomes "too broad" unless there is a way of choosing (typically embedded in the question).
